# For char * varable, how to view its value in debug mode

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I composed below code to readback binary files by VC2017. In debug mode, I like to see the values in "buffer". but I could not see readable values. 
my questions are:

1. how can I view the readable result?
2. I did "sizeof(buffer)", it returned 4, which was less than what I expected. I expected the buffer to be same size and the file size. why?

Thank you very much for enlightening me.

```
char* read_back(const char* filename) 
{
    FILE* pFile;
    long lSize;
    char* buffer;

    pFile = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if (pFile == NULL)
    {
        fputs("File error", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell(pFile);
    rewind(pFile); // set file pos at the begining

    // copy the file into the buffer:
    buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize);
    size_t result = fread(buffer, 1, lSize, pFile);

    if (result != lSize)
    {
        fputs("Reading error", stderr);
        exit(3);
    }

    fclose(pFile);

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: When you use `sizeof` on a pointer, you get the size of the *pointer*, not the data it might point to. You need to keep track of the size yourself in the program. And in C++, if you want a string use `std::string`. And C++ streams instead of the old C file-handling.

Comment: Don't use `malloc`. Use `new`. Actually scratch that, you should be using `std::vector<char>` instead of buffer at all. Or even using the `iostream` capabilities of c++.

Comment: *"I composed below code to readback binary files [...] but I could not see readable values"* Binary data isn't "readable" like that. Let's say for instance your binary data is `AA AF B3 58 23 B3`, how would you "read" that? Perhaps you can change your debugger to display the content pointed at by the `char*` to be shown as hex instead of text, but it's most likely not going to be something human-readable.

Comment: Is it really C++? I see only C code.

Comment: If you want to read arbitrary data, then use `std::vector` instead of a string. And `uint8_t` (or possibly `int8_t`) instead of `char`.

Comment: thank you for all above comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do your code in C++ (not the C code that you actually have)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string read_back(const char* filename)
{
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios_base::binary);
    std::ostringstream buffer;
    buffer << file.rdbuf();
    return buffer.str();
}
```

It returns a std::string not a char* but that's a good thing, because you don't have the issue of remembering to have to free the allocated memory.

As has been explained you misunderstand how pointers and sizeof work. Avoid pointers, they're hard.

Comment: sorry again, I take back my above comment. let me try again

Comment: @user10293779 apologies typo, it should be `rdbuf`